# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ not booting into retropie after using a mp4 splashscreen

Tags: raspbian, retropie, emulation

I replaced the default theme with futura-dark-V and selected a mp4 splashscreen. When I turn it on, everything works normal until the splashscreen. After the splashscreen, it says:

lvl0:   Error creating SDL window!
    Could not get EGL display
lvl0:   Renderer failed to initialize!
lvl0:   Window failed to initialize!

At this point, the device ignores all input coming from the keyboard (except some special letters). Please tell me how can I fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove the rpi memory card, plug it into computer and mount the `root` partition
2. go to `/home/pi/RetroPie/splashscreens/`
3. remove the video file
4. unmount the drive, return the memory card to rpi and boot it

The video should be gone and the rpi should boot again.

When using the video splashscreens be sure about video format, check more info about it at [Adding a custom video](https://howchoo.com/g/odkwmdnizdq/how-to-change-or-set-a-custom-retropie-splash-screen#adding-a-custom-video) page.